# set default value in class constructor C#

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis, static-variables, variable-assignment

I need a default value set and many different pages access and update..initially can I set the default value in the class constructor like this?  What is the proper way to do this in C# .NET?

```
public class ProfitVals
{

    private static double _hiprofit;

    public static Double HiProfit
    {
        get { return _hiprofit; }

        set { _hiprofit = value; }
    }

    // assign default value

    HiProfit = 0.09;

}
```

Comment: why not just do it in the declaration: private static double _hiprofit = 0.09D;

Comment: is that the best / proper way to do it??
that looks fine to me.

Comment: it is personal preference IMO, both are viable approaches

Comment: There are performance implications.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can put it in the declaration: `private static double _hiprofit = 0.09;`
Or if it's a more complicated initialization you can do it in the static constructor:

```
   private static double _hiprofit; 
   static ProfitVals() 
   {
      _hiprofit = 0.09;
   }
```

The former is preferred as the latter pays a performance penalty: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/04/17/115300.aspx

Answer (score 6):

No, you would have to surround the assignment to the property with an actual *static constructor* like so:

```
class ProfitVals
{
    public static double HiProfit { ... }

    static ProfitVals()  // static ctor
    {
       HiProfit = 0.09;
    }
}
```

Note: a static constructor can not be declared private/public and cannot have parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, you just need to use a [constructor.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87.aspx)

```
public class ProfitVals {
    private static double _hiprofit;

    public static Double HiProfit
    {
        get { return _hiprofit; }

        set { _hiprofit = value; }
    }

    public ProfitVals() {
        // assign default value
        HiProfit = 0.09;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is an _instance_ constructor.

Comment: this won't work - now every time you create a `ProfitVals` instance `HiProfit` is set to its default value.

Comment: @Henk - yes it is; I thought that's what the OP was asking for?  @BrokenGlass - given the OP's statement "I need a default value set", why is this a breaking implementation?

Comment: @48klo, can you think of a scenario for a static (shared) property that is reset by each instance?

Comment: the default values is only set until its changed .. but it should not reset when the class is accessed.

Comment: OK, I'm slow - I just noticed the static keywords littered all over the place there now.  In my example, the default value wouldn't change when it's simply accessed, but it would change when a new instance is constructed (which still makes it dangerous for your use case).