# Set updated date

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm using EF database first

I have a table with a 'date updated' column in it. It needs to have the current datetime when a record is updated in it. I am using EF so I can't edit any autogenerated model classes. I don't want to edit T4 templates because I assume that will be overwritten if I upgrade EF

To solve a different problem I followed this: http://www.ozkary.com/2015/01/add-data-annotations-to-entity.html to generate a 'buddy' class which as far as I can tell just extend the autogenerated EF class

So then I followed the answer to this: [set default value in class constructor C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251621/set-default-value-in-class-constructor-c-sharp) which seems to show a solution to what I need. However when I test, the `DateUpdated` is not changed

Here's part of my autogenerated class. You can see `DTUpdated` in here

```
namespace bt2.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Task
    {
        public int Task_ID { get; set; }
        public int TaskType_ID { get; set; }
        public int Emp_ID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DTInserted { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DTUpdated { get; set; }

        public virtual TaskType TaskType { get; set; }
        public virtual Task Tasks1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Task Task1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's my 'buddy' class where I tried to add extra code to the autogenerated class:

```
namespace bt2.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(TaskMD))]
    public partial class Task
    {
    }

    internal sealed class TaskMD
    {
        [DisplayName("ID")]
        public int Task_ID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Task Type")]

        public int TaskType_ID { get; set; }

        public System.DateTime DTUpdated {
            get { return DateTime.Now; }
            set { this.DTUpdated = value; }
        }
    }
```

As far as I can tell this second class is extending the original class

I want to solve my problem but I also want to understand whats going on in more detail here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the Context class is a Partial class you can create your own partial class with an overload of the `SaveChanges` method.

In this method you can use reflection to get the `DTUpated` property and set the Updated Date Time Value. (if the name of the property is the same, if the name is NOT same pass in the name as a parameter)

Something like the following.

```
public partial class TBCompanyEntities
{

    public void SaveChanges(object o)
    {
        try
        {
            var propertyInfo = o.GetType().GetProperty("DTUpdated");

            // This hasn't been tested by me yet - will test and update if need changes
            if(propertyInfo != null)
                propertyInfo.SetValue(o, Convert.ChangeType(DateTime.UtcNow, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //  Logging.Log.Error(ex);
        }

        base.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```

Then in your code instead of calling `dbContxt.SaveChanges();` you can call

```
dbContext.SaveChanges(YOUR_ENTITY_OBJECT);
```

Example:

```
            using (var dbContext = new TBCompanyEntities())
            {
                // Entity with DTUpdated
                var notification = dbContext.NotificationArchives.First(s => s.iNotificationId == 1);
                notification.bIsRead = true;
                dbContext.SaveChanges(notification);

                //Entity without DTUpdated
                var asset = dbContext.Assets.First(s => s.iAssetId == 1);
                asset.iDriverId = null;
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
```

**EDIT:**

An override is when the parameters of the overridden method are same as the base method.

So you will have to do something like this:

```
public partial class TBCompanyEntities
{

    public override void SaveChanges()
    {
       //TODO: Here you will have to detect which entity has been modified/updated.
       // This should be possible, by using the Track Entity Changes features

               var modifiedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();


        base.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```

here is a good link of override in which the author tracks changes to Entities and then creates a Log. (like Audit Log)

https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/entity-change-tracking-using-dbcontext-in-entity-framework-6/

Comment: This is a good way. You can also simply override the SaveChanges method and set current datetime to the UpdatedTime field.

Comment: yes - but what if all tables don't have the DTUpdated column - and the OP wants to keep existing method

Comment: That's already taken care of right!  if(propertyInfo != null) indicates that the property exists. If it doesn't exist, it won't bother. I used similar logic.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide such a detailed answer. Does this mean I would need to go into all controllers that are updating (not many, probably six) and change the call to `SaveChanges`? of code? The thing is, I was actually going to go into my controllers and just set the `DTUpdated` property in there manually but I thought there must be a way to somehow override the EF classes to do this 'natively'. I don't want to add code that I don't fully understand. Can you explain why the existing code didn't do what I thought it should?

Comment: I don't understand your existing solution. But if all your tables need the DTUpdated field then u can do an override instead of overload of the SaveChanges method

Comment: Right now I am adding this to only one table but it makes perfect sense to add this to all tables in future. I'm not sure what an override is though. If your solution above is an overload then maybe I'm starting to grasp it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what's happening in there but here are some suggestions:

1. You can generate Attributes to each entity and each property in the entity. It's a little tricky and you can even generate keys for the entities. You can eliminate extending that class and creating metadata. This reflects your database schema. I used this approach in my project and it worked.
2. Auto generated files using T4 templates is a one time event(unless you have some changes and you want to re-generate all the entities). So, it's advisable to have it disconnected and use only the generated entities in your project.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It's database first so the entities will definitely be regenerated in future as the database changes.